# Не могу получить ссылку из строкового ресурса для массива в коде Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, activity, android-resources

В массив обьектов в коде пытаюсь вставить ссылку из строкового ресурса

```
 public static final Regiments[] regiments = {
        new Regiments(context.getResources().getString(R.string.name_regiment_0), "bla-bla-bla", R.drawable.logo_leg),
        new Regiments(context.getResources().getString(R.string.name_regiment_1), "bla-bla-bla", R.drawable.logo_leg),
};
```

но появляется предупреждение о возможном возникновении NullPointerException и приложение падает.
Пробовал сохранять в переменную и проверять ее на null , тогда код запускается, но появляется предупреждение что переменная все равно null  и поле не заполняется.

Comment: Покажите текст ошибки, когда падает.

Comment: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: У вас переменная `context` равна `null` - это значит что вы используете её раньше чем присваиваете её значение. Статический инициализатор выполняется при загрузке класса, то есть при первом его упоминании в коде - поэтому инициализация `context` должна быть выше по коду, но в Андроиде принципе недопустимо хранить контекст в статиках. Почему не сделать так же как и с картинками - использовать id строки, а саму строку пусть потом добывает виджет.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался вашим советом. Все работает, не стал работать с контекстом
' static final Regiments[] regiments = {
            new Regiments(R.string.name_regiment_0, R.string.name_description_0, R.drawable.logo_leg),
            new Regiments(R.string.name_regiment_1, R.string.name_description_1, R.drawable.logo_leg),
    };'

Comment: Решение лучше опубликовать в поле ответа и отметить его галкой как принятое (когда будет доступно). Всем будет понятно что проблема решена, а вы репутацию себе заработаете.

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказали, все работает, сделал также как и с картинками ,использовал ссылки на строковый ресурс...

```
 static final Regiments[] regiments = {
        new Regiments(R.string.name_regiment_0, R.string.name_description_0, R.drawable.logo_leg),
        new Regiments(R.string.name_regiment_1, R.string.name_description_1, R.drawable.logo_leg),
};
```

...а обрабатывал уже виджете.

```
 TextView name = findViewById(R.id.regiment_title);
    name.setText(regimentNew.getNameID());
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы избежать возможного `NullPointerException`, вам нужно вызывать метод `getResources()` из контекста, который уже инициализирован. Если вы вызываете его из `context` внутри класса, который еще не создан, то это может вызвать ошибку. Рекомендуется передавать `context` в качестве параметра в конструктор класса и сохранять его в переменной класса для дальнейшего использования.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Context context;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        Regiments[] regiments = {
            new Regiments(context.getResources().getString(R.string.name_regiment_0), "bla-bla-bla", R.drawable.logo_leg),
            new Regiments(context.getResources().getString(R.string.name_regiment_1), "bla-bla-bla", R.drawable.logo_leg),
        };
    }
}
```

Также убедитесь, что вы правильно определили строковые ресурсы в файле `strings.xml`.